# Set same value to all object in a list , java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list for model class as below

```
public class ContentDatum implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
String id;

@SerializedName("renewable")
@Expose
boolean renewable;

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
String name;

@SerializedName("seasId")
@Expose
String seasId;
}
```

I have all the values in my list for id, name and renewable. I want to update `seasId` for whole list with a default value. One way is to iterate through the list and update value like

```
for (int i = 0; i <adapterData.size() ; i++) {
            adapterData.get(i).setSeasId("kf3-4n34-43");
        }
```

Is there any other function I can make use of do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the default value in your declaration?

```
public class ContentDatum implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
String id;

@SerializedName("renewable")
@Expose
boolean renewable;

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
String name;

@SerializedName("seasId")
@Expose
String seasId = "kf3-4n34-43";
}
```

Comment: value is to be changed at runtime so can't use default

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use streams (java 8 or later):

```
adapterData.stream().forEach(elt -> elt.setSeasId("kf3-4n34-43"));
```

or

```
for (ContentDatum cd : adapterData) cd.setSeasId("kf3-4n34-43");
```

But it is basically the same as a one liner, isnt it ?

If you want to set a default value, and not an update Jj Tuibeo answer is right

I'm curious if there is a better/smarter way to do this !

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate, there is no way around that. But you can make it simpler and clearer:

```
adapterData.forEach(
        datum -> datum.setSeasId("kf3-4n34-43")
);
```

Remember if you are going to do that repeatedly with different constant values, create a function for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java 8 List.replaceAll method as in the following example:

```
List<ContentDatum> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();
ContentDatum cd1 = new ContentDatum();
cd1.id = "1";
ContentDatum cd2 = new ContentDatum();
cd2.id = "2";
adapterData.add(cd1);
adapterData.add(cd2);

adapterData.replaceAll(ad-> {ad.seasId = "X"; return ad;});
System.out.println("Result: "+adapterData);
```

The above will produce the following output (assuming you have added a toString() method in ContentDatum class:

```
Result: [ContentDatum{id='1', seasId='X'}, ContentDatum{id='2', seasId='X'}]
```